# Android React-native app e2e testing with webdriverio. It doesn't show the app until the test fails

Tags: react-native, webdriver-io

I have installed appium and webdriverio to run e2e tests.

I am at first just trying to click on a button but the test keeps trying to find it while the emulator just shows the phone settings.

When the test finally fails the emulator shows the app (with the button).

If I tell the test to wait many seconds, it will wait on the emulator showing the settings and then it will try to find the button on the settings until it fails.

Thanks.